# Automatic selection of lowest information criterion comes with warning

Tags: time-series, python, aic, arma, bic

I am building a forecasting model (ARMA) and found the very useful code-object `arma_order_select_ic`(see code below). It all works, however, each calculation comes with a warning (see warning) which lowers running speed, especially when using more than 6 maximum p and q values. (y = time series, 1 indexed column)

code:

```
y = indexed_df
    res = arma_order_select_ic(y, max_ar=8, max_ma=8, ic=['aic', 'bic', 'hqic'], trend='c', fit_kw=dict(method='css'))
    print res
    print ('AIC-order: {}' .format(res.aic_min_order))
    print ('BIC-order: {}' .format(res.bic_min_order))
    print ('HQIC-order: {}' .format(res.hqic_min_order))
```

warning:

```
/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels-0.6.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/statsmodels/base/model.py:466: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals
  "Check mle_retvals", ConvergenceWarning)
```

does someone know how i might solve this problem, i.e. how to make sure that Maximum Likelihood optimization converges?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally one cannot be sure, problem is not about some particular programming language.

Parameter estimation for ARMA models is generally an non-linear optimization problem which might not have such nice properties as some other optimization problems.

You might want to generate some try/catch branching and perhaps give end users some signal that they have to act.

Comment: @ Analyst: thanks for your answer. What do you mean by 'generating some try/catch branching...'? I was hoping to get a hint where i might have to change my code or alternatively my time series. Btw, the warning does not appear when using 'max_ar=3, max_ma=3' or below. Is it possible that this comes from the nature of the time series i.e. non-stationarity?

Comment: @PeterKnutsen I meant that you need an error handling in your code if next step is somehow conditional on your forecasts or model building in the previous step.